# Remove/Add items from a record's child collection when updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I develop a web application using Entity framework 6 ORM. I've encountered a problem hopefully I can get help.

Say I have the following models in my tables:

```
public class Letter
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public string Topic {get; set;}

   public string content {get; set;}

   public List<Destination> Destinations {get; set;}
}

public class Destination 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

In this method I get a letter received from clients form. This letter contains an Id and is found in my database, but all of it's properties as well as *navigation properties* - Destinations could have changed (client decided to send the letter to more destinations or less destinations than before - list size can change but not context of each destination).
I fill in the destinations list according to Ids the client supplied. Meaning the destinations are tracked by the context.

```
public void UpdateLetter(Letter updatedLetter, List<int> destinationsIds)
{
    updatedLetter.Destinations = context.Set<Destination>().Where(x => destinationsIds.Contains(x => x.Id)).ToList();

    context.Set<Letter>().Attach(updatedLetter);

    context.Entry(updatedLetter).State = EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The above code work only for the scalar properties. What should I change in order for the destinations list to be updated according to the Id's the client supplied me?

How can I tell entity framework that the list of destinations was changed? (Items could have been added or removed)?

My problem is that when saving the changes, only simple properties are updated correctly, but the list does not change

Example for the update I mean:

Lets say I have those Destinations in my database:

```
dest1 : Id = 1, Name = "Destination1"
dest2 : Id = 2, Name = "Destination2"
dest3 : Id = 3, Name = "Destination3"
dest4 : Id = 4, Name = "Destination4"


var listBeforeUpdate = new List<Destination>
{
    dest1,
    dest2,
    dest3
}
```

Now, after updating a letter:

```
var listAfterUpdate = new List<Destination>
{
    dest1,
    dest3,
    dest4
}
```

How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Comment: Why? Is is because you automatically want to send out a new letter?  A change is an event.  So you want to create a new event.  Then when a change occurs the List class would trigger the event.  You also would need to register a method to call like UpdateLetter() to process the event.

Comment: I don't follow. Client saved himself a letter to be sent later. Than he decided to change the destinations/title/content, etc.. All regular properties are updated thanks changing the state to modified, yet I don't know how to set the new destinations accordingly

Comment: You should just be able to change the 'Name' property of the Destination.  The destination is a List object so you need an index Destinations[0].Name

Comment: I guess you still did not fully understand. I'm not trying to change the destinations inner properties. I want to change the Letter's destinations. Meaning add another destination or remove destinations.

Comment: You want to change the following : public List<Destination> Destinations {get; set;}.  The instance is newLetter so you are changing newLetter.Destinations[0].Name.  The destinations are a List<> object which can be added, deleted, or modified.

Comment: Why am I changing the newLetter.Destinations[0]?

Comment: Just an example and to show that object is an array.

Comment: See my example, I hope what I ask is clear now

Answer (score -1):

Code would look something like code below.  It would make snese in this case just to replace all the destinations with the results from database.  I assumed the query  to the database would fill a datatable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Letter newLetter = new Letter();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,"Destination1"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2,"Destination2"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3,"Destination3"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4,"Destination4"});

            newLetter.Destinations = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Destination()
            {
                Id = x.Field<int>("Id"),
                Name = x.Field<string>("Name")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Letter
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Topic { get; set; }

        public string content { get; set; }

        public List<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how it relates. I'm using entity framework 6

Comment: How are you querying database?  Is results using a  DataAdapter?  DataAdapter has fill method to create a DataTable.  So I put your sample query results into a datatable so it would look exactly like results from DataAdapter, then add the destinations to your Letter.

Comment: I'm using LINQ, hopefully I can stick to it

Comment: Well I'm using linq also : dt.AsEnumerable() where dt is the datatable returned from the database query.